# Alfresco Content-Service ADF APP. Enabling CORS on clientside?

Tags: javascript, typescript, proxy, cors, alfresco

I am creating an ACS ADF App and I want to use a Server which is not on my localhost. I have configured the "app.config.json" file and the "proxy.conf.json" file as described here: 'https://community.alfresco.com/community/application-development-framework/blog/2017/06/20/adf-cors-solving-strategies'. But I still get the following Error Messages: [image]

I have also changed configuration on serverside as described in this tutorial: https://rssupport.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ALFC/pages/67207177/Setup+Guide+for+cross+domain+CORS

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: "Enabling CORS on clientside?" — You can't. You can only do it server side.

Comment: You can do proxy configurations on clientside to "solve" CORS, but I don't know which configurations I need.

Comment: If you were to use a proxy, then you still need to write a proxy on your server.

Comment: So there is no possibillity so solve this on clientside for example with a header or something the like?

Comment: Would you like it if `evilwebsite.com` could add a header and gain access to the data in HTTP requests your browser sent to `gmail.com` or `yourbank.com`?

Comment: No of course not. Do you have an idea what I can change on serveside additional to that i have already done?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable CORS on serverside . you can Download the **enablecors-1.0.jar** from the Alfresco Nexus Repository. Save the enablecors-1.0.jar file in the $ALF_HOME/modules/platform folder. Restart Alfresco.
or

Add the below keys in alfresco.global.properties to enable CORS from alfresco side
**cors.enabled=true** and 
**security.csrf.disabled=true**